# Why is my REST call undefined?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

Newbie looking for help here...I have a function to return the current logged in user's name. When I try to access the user's info in a console log as seen below, It is returning undefined. Where am I going wrong? Thanks for you help!

```
  function createContent(data, listName){
        function GetCurrentUser() {
        var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
        var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
        $.ajax({
          url : requestUri,
          contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
          headers : requestHeaders,
          success : function(data){
          alert(data.d.Title);
            return data;
          }
        });
        }

        var arr = data.d.results;
        $(".save").on("click",function(){
                event.preventDefault();
            $("input.title").each(function(){
                var request = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.allItemsTitle").text();
                var title = $(this).val();
                var taskProperties = {
                    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListItem' },
                    'Rank': title,
                    'RequestName': request
                };

                for(var i = 0;i <= arr.length -1;i++){
                    var item = arr[i];          
                    console.log("request = " + request);
                    console.log("item.RequestName = " + item.RequestName);
//The below console.log is returning "current user = undefined.", instead of "current user = My User Name"
                    console.log("current user = " + GetCurrentUser() + ".");
                    console.log("item.Author[Title] = " + item.Author["Title"]);

                    if(request == item.RequestName && GetCurrentUser() == item.Author["Title"]){
                            console.log('Item has been created successfully');
                    } else {console.log("NO ITEMS CREATED");}
                } 
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of reasons:

1. AJAX calls are **a**synchronous.  In your `console.log` statement, you care calling your `GetCurrentUser` function, which kicks off the call to the REST services, but the `console.log` is expecting `GetCurrentUser` to return some value *immediately*, which it cannot do, because AJAX calls are async and therefore you are still waiting for the response from the server while the `console.log` is trying to write something.
2. Your `GetCurrentUser` function is not going to return the data the way you think it should, because your success callback function is nested inside your `GetCurrentUser` function.  So when your success callback does `return data`, it's really only returning the `data` object into the scope of the `GetCurrentUser` function.  You could try something like this:

```
var restResponse; // defined outside the scope of the GetCurrentUser function

function GetCurrentUser() {
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d.Title);
            restResponse = data; // assign the data to a variable outside the current scope
        }
    });
}
```

BUT that still won't solve the timing issue.  Now, since calling jQuery's `ajax` function creates a Deferred object, what you could do is have your `GetCurrentUser` function return the Deferred out to the rest of your code so that you can have the code be waiting in the correct place, like:

```
function createContent(data, listName) {
    function GetCurrentUser() {
        var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
        var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };

        return $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: requestHeaders
        });
    }

    var arr = data.d.results;
    $(".save").on("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();

        $("input.title").each(function () {
            var request = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.allItemsTitle").text();
            var title = $(this).val();
            var taskProperties = {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListItem' },
                'Rank': title,
                'RequestName': request
            };

            var currentUserRequest = GetCurrentUser();
            // this has created the request to the server, but we still have to wait 
            // for the response from the server to be returned back to the code.
            // also, we want to name the data that is returned in a way that disambiguates 
            // from the "data" object passed into the "createContent" function,
            // because that "data" object is still in scope here.
            currentUserRequest.done(function (userData) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
                    var item = arr[i];
                    console.log("request = " + request);
                    console.log("item.RequestName = " + item.RequestName);
                    console.log("current user = " + userData.d.Title + ".");
                    console.log("item.Author[Title] = " + item.Author["Title"]);

                    if (request == item.RequestName && userData.d.Title == item.Author["Title"]) {
                        console.log('Item has been created successfully');
                    } else { console.log("NO ITEMS CREATED"); }
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

[jQuery "Deferred" documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

Comment: Thanks so much! That was extremely helpful and solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Timing issues aside, your ajax success function just returns the entire data response, which would not have matched your item.Author["Title"], unless that item had an entire SharePoint user object as it's author title.